# How can build a model that will predict duplicate records in your dataset?

Tags: python, duplicates, classification

What are the algorithms that will predict duplicates in your dataset.
For example -

```
Name Marks
A    100
B     90
C     80
A    100
```

I need something like this -

```
Name  Marks S/D
A     100   Single
B     90    Single
C     80    Single
A     100   Duplicate
```

I'm looking for some algorithms that can help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C','A'],'Marks': [100, 90, 80, 100]})

df['res'] = df.duplicated().map({False:"Single", True:"Duplicated"})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Name  Marks         res
0    A    100      Single
1    B     90      Single
2    C     80      Single
3    A    100  Duplicated
```